# Moment Generating function of $P(Y=k) = \frac{c}{(a+|k|)^\frac{5}{2}}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I'm having a hard time calculating and understanding why the mgf of thie function $$P(Y=k)=\frac{c}{(a+|k|)^\frac{5}{2}}$$ is infinite when t>0. Can someone explain please?

Comment: It might be worth stating $a>0$ and $k$ ranges over all integers and $t$ is the variable in  $\mathbb E\left[e^{tY}\right]$.  What did you try?

Comment: I don't see the sum converging even with $a$ is positive, unless I'm missing something in my computatation.

Comment: @Math1000  It has some similarities to a Pareto distribution with $\alpha = \frac32$ so you should expect there to be a $c$ which works for a given $a>0$ to make the sum be $1$; the first moment will then be $0$ but there will not be a finite second or higher moment